# how can i show mysql data alphabeticaly

Tags: php

i have the following mysql table....

```
-----------------------
id customer_name date 
-----------------------
```

now let me know the query with which i will able to show data Order by alphabeticaly...

where values of customer_fields are like testkhan, rafae, ibrahm and i want to show them as

ibrahm
rafae
testkhan

Comment: note that you have to have table charset properly set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
… ORDER BY some_column
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this, assuming the table name is 'Customers' and you want to order by customer_name descending:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
ORDER BY customer_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer_name 
FROM Customers
ORDER BY customer_name ASC
```